# How to check which matching group was used to match (boost-regex)

Tags: c++, regex, parsing, c++11, boost-regex

I'm using boost::regex to parse some formatting string where '%' symbol is escape character. Because I do not have much experience with boost::regex, and with regex at all to be honest I do some trial and error. This code is some kind of prototype that I came up with.

```
std::string regex_string = 
            "(?:%d\\{(.*)\\})|"                   //this group will catch string for formatting time
            "(?:%([hHmMsSqQtTlLcCxXmMnNpP]))|"    //symbols that have some meaning
            "(?:\\{(.*?)\\})|"                    //some other groups
            "(?:%(.*?)\\s)|"
            "(?:([^%]*))";

    boost::regex regex;
    boost::smatch match;

    try
    {
        regex.assign(regex_string, boost::regex_constants::icase);
        boost::sregex_iterator res(pattern.begin(), pattern.end(), regex);
        //pattern in line above is string which I'm parsing
        boost::sregex_iterator end;
        for(; res != end; ++res)
        {
            match = *res;
            output << match.get_last_closed_paren();
            //I want to know if the thing that was just written to output is from group describing time string
            output << "\n";
        }


    }
    catch(boost::regex_error &e)
    {
        output<<"regex error\n";
    }
```

And this works pretty good, on the output I have exactly what I want to catch. But I do not know from which group it is. I could do something like `match[index_of_time_group]!=""` but this is kind of fragile, and doesn't look too good. If I change `regex_string` index that was pointing on group catching string for formatting time could also change.

Is there a neat way to do this? Something like naming groups? I'll be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`boost::sub_match::matched`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/sub_match.html#boost_regex.sub_match.matched) bool member:

```
if(match[index_of_time_group].matched) process_it(match);
```

It is also possible to use named groups in regexp like: `(?<name_of_group>.*)`, and with this above line could be changed to:

```
if(match["name_of_group"].matched) process_it(match);
```

Comment: Thanks! After a little tweak I came up with following solution.
I changed part of regexp: `(?:%d\\{(?<time>.*)\\})`, so now it is named group. With this I could use code you proposed like: `if(match["time"].matched) output<<"It was time string after all";`. Probably I'll do some more tweaking along the way, but I'll take liberty to edit your post and mark it as my answer. ;) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically build `regex_string` from pairs of name/pattern, and return a name->index mapping as well as the regex.  Then write some code that determines if the match comes from a given name.

If you are insane, you can do it at compile time (the mapping from tag to index that is).  It isn't worth it.